# Jasper reports - Upgrade jasper compiler - JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile fails

Tags: compiler-construction, report

I'm using jasper reports (version 4.0.1) in a Java project (with maven).
I was asked to update the jasper compiler to last version, right now we are using jasper-compiler-jdt but I was asked to use the same that ireport uses, and I think it's jdt-compiler-3.1.1.jar, right?

But I have some questions about that.

Is it available in a maven respository? I can't find it there.
Should I used jdt-compiler-3.1.1.jar or maybe org.eclipse.jdt.core ?

I tried with both but I'm getting errors when trying to compile jrxml files:

```
Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
 package net.sf.jasperreports.engine does not exist
 import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*;"
```

I added libraries to classpath.
So, I would like to know:

- which is the right compiler to use (we don't want to use jasper-compiler-jdt anymore)
- how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

1.jasper reports (version 4.0.1)  version must equal ireport's version.So you should use ireport4.0.1 to design you report.

2.how to make it work? You can download  iReport-Ultimate-Guide-3.5.pdf and jasperreports_ultimate_guide_3.5.pdf two pdf files to learn how to use.

3.Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using netbeans I can suggest you something. When you install it, netbeans IDE automatically set to use old jdk. The JDK you have installed is kept aside and old compiler is used. You can go in settings to change it.